# Как скопировать текст через Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, copy

Мне надо скопировать текст с сайта, который находится в class="emailbox-input opentip" (или же id="mail") и вставить в другое поле, никак не могу это реализовать.
Помогите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, как-то так:

```
# Запоминаем текст из первого объекта
text = driver.find_element_by_id("mail").text

# Здесь идентификатор input'а, в который хотите вставить текст
input_element = driver.find_element_by_id("my_input") 
input_element.send_keys(text)
```

Кстати, в selenium с версии 4.3.0 теперь убрали методы `find_element_by_id` и `find_element_by_name`, поэтому, если используете его, то следует использовать метод `find_element`, вот пример для версии 4.3.0:

```
text = driver.find_element("id", "mail").text

# Здесь идентификатор input'а, в который хотите вставить текст
input_element = driver.find_element("id", "my_input")
input_element.send_keys(text)
```

В данном примере сначала находим в разметке блок с Id `'mail'` и сохраняем текст, хранящийся в нём в переменную `text`. Далее, находим в разметке элемент input с нужным Id, в примере указан id `my_input`, и в него записываем сохранённый в переменной текст, словно пользователь через клавиатуру его записал туда.

`driver` - это объект webdriver.

Comment: Во 2-м коде, как я понял, делается input по id?
А мне надо только лишь скопировать по id или class

Comment: Здесь ничто не "делается", он находит в существующей HTML разметке уже существующий input и в него записывает полученный текст, словно пользователь с клавиатуры ввёл туда этот текст.